# Annihilator of a prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$ which does not contain a regular element. Claim: $\operatorname{ann}P\neq0$.

I am struggling to prove this claim. Can anyone present a proof? Thanks

Comment: Such a prime ideal is necessarily contained in an associated prime and then the claim is clear.